# How do I add values from radio and input text to another input text when selected?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, textinput

I have a radio list to pick a payment value. When you choose the payment value it adds to the amount text input.

I also have an option for 'other amount'.

What I would like to do is click 'other amount', show a hidden text input, when you add a value, it adds to the 'amount text input'.

If you then click back on one of the other radio values it hides the 'other-amount' text input and the value is changed to whichever selection was made.

HTML:

```
<div id="donation">
    <input type="radio" name="my-input" id="0" value="$10.00" />
    $10.00<br />
    <input type="radio" name="my-input" id="1" value="$25.00" />
    $25.00<br />
    <input type="radio" name="my-input" id="2" value="$50.00" />
    $50.00<br />
    <input type="radio" name="my-input" id="3" value="$2500.00" />
    $2500.00<br />
    <input type="radio" name="my-input" id="other" value="Other Amount" />
    Other Amount
</div>

<input type="text" id="other-amount" name="other-amount" />

<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" readonly="readonly" />
```

Javascript so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#donation input[type=radio]").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == $("#amount").val();
}).attr('checked', true);

$("#donation").live("change", function() {

    $("#amount").val($(this).find("input[type=radio]:checked").attr("value"));
});
});
```

Comment: jQuery `.live()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the value from one text box to another you can this

```
 $('#other-amount').on('keyup', function(){
          $("#amount").val($(this).val());     
  });
```

To hide it on any other radio select

```
 $('input:radio[id!=other]').on('click', function(){
    $('#other-amount').hide();
});
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FqrXh/)

Comment: Thanks hsalama that works really well. What if I wanted to clear the 'other-amount' when another value was clicked - so that if you go back to it, it has no value?

Comment: Just do `$('#other-amount').val('');`